# TCP socket connection is succesful but not able to write anything on output stream

Tags: ios, swift, sockets, tcp, tcpsocket

Typically TCP socket delegate get called with "bytesAvailble" after successfully recieving any message from client to server. Connection is getting successful. getting call back with "SpaceAvailable" messages are being sent but not getting call back. No problem in client because the old Objective-C code is working fine.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, StreamDelegate {
    var inputStream: InputStream?
    var outputStream: OutputStream?
    
    var messageQueue = [String]()
    
    var timer : Timer!
    var writeReady = false
    
    var timeInterval = 2.0
    
    var clientSocket: Int32!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        self.startTCP()
    }
    
    func startTCP(){
        self.connectToServer(host: "192.168.0.200", port: 50001)
    }
    
    func connectToServer(host: String, port: Int) {
        Stream.getStreamsToHost(withName: host, port: port, inputStream: &inputStream, outputStream: &outputStream)
        
        inputStream?.delegate = self
        outputStream?.delegate = self
        
        inputStream?.schedule(in: RunLoop.current, forMode: .common)
        outputStream?.schedule(in: RunLoop.current, forMode: .common)
        
        inputStream?.open()
        outputStream?.open()
        print("connection successful")
    }
    
    func stream(_ aStream: Stream, handle eventCode: Stream.Event) {
        switch eventCode {
        case .openCompleted:
            if aStream == outputStream {
                print("open completed for output stream")
                writeReady = true
                sendConnectionMessage()
                startHeartBeat()
            }
        case .hasBytesAvailable:
            print("bytes avaialble")
            guard let inputStream = inputStream else {
                print("Input stream is nil")
                return
            }
            let bufferSize = 1024
            var buffer = Array<UInt8>(repeating: 0, count: bufferSize)
            let bytesRead = inputStream.read(&buffer, maxLength: bufferSize)
            if bytesRead > 0 {
                let receivedMessage = String(bytes: buffer, encoding: .utf8)!
                print("Received message: \(receivedMessage)")
            }
        case .errorOccurred:
            print("Error occurred: \(aStream.streamError!.localizedDescription)")
            disconnect()
            stopHeartBeat()
            startTCP()
        case .endEncountered:
            print("End encountered")
        case .hasSpaceAvailable:
            print("space available")
            
            if(aStream == self.outputStream)
            {
                handleMessageQueue()
            }
        default:
            print("Unknown event")
        }
    }
    
    func handleMessageQueue(){
        if messageQueue.count>0 {
            if let message = messageQueue.first {
                sendMessage(message)
                messageQueue.removeFirst()
            }
        } else {
            //handle empty queue
        }
    }
    
    @objc func sendConnectionMessage() {
        messageQueue.append("{\"msg.type\":\"Connection\",\"source.address\":\"192.168.0.126\"}")
    }
    
    func sendMessage(_ message: String) {
        if !writeReady{ return }
        
        guard let outputStream = outputStream else {
            print("Output stream is nil")
            return
        }

        let data = message.data(using: .utf8)!
        print("writing")
        //        let bytesWritten = outputStream.write(data: data)
        
        let bytesWritten = data.withUnsafeBytes { outputStream.write($0, maxLength: data.count) }
        
        if bytesWritten < 0 {
            print("Error sending message")
        } else {
            print("Sent message: \(message)")
        }
    }
    
    func startHeartBeat(){
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: timeInterval, repeats: true, block: { _ in
            self.sendMessage("{\"msg.data\":[{\"Dev.ID\":\"0\",\"Dev.inst\":\"0\"}],\"msg.type\":\"Register\"}\n")
        })
    }
    
    func stopHeartBeat(){
        if timer == nil { return }
        timer.invalidate()
    }
    
    func disconnect() {
        inputStream?.close()
        outputStream?.close()
        inputStream = nil
        outputStream = nil
    }
}
```

Comment: Your understanding of TCP appears to be flawed, it's not a message oriented protocol and even though you can *write* whole messages at a time (maybe..), the other end can receive an abitrarily cut chunk of the resulting stream at a time. May be more or less than a full message, by pure chance.

Comment: Most likely your server is just a faulty, and you just stumbled across a race condition where you ended up sending the connection notification and heartbeat such that they ended up being received in a single chunk.